# Tornado with jQuery Webcam Plugin Problem

Tags: python, jquery-plugins, tornado

I'm using Tornado Webserver and the jQuery Webcam Plugin.

Everything is going fine except that I don't think i'm getting the raw data properly. I'm getting "FFD8FFE000104A46494600010100000100010000FFDB0084000503040404030504040405050506070C08070707070F0B0B090C110F1212110F111113161C1713141A1511111821181A1D1D1F1F1F13172224221E241C1E1F1E010505050706070E08080E1E1411141E1E1E1E1E1E1E1E1E1E1E1E1E1E1E1E1E1E1E1E1E1E1E1E1E1E1E1E1E1E1E1E1E1E1" for my data.

frontend:

```
$("#camera").webcam({width: 320,
            height: 240,
            mode: "save",
            swffile: "/static/js/jscam.swf",
            onTick: function() {
            alert('OnTick');},
            onCapture: function() {
                webcam.capture();
                var x = webcam.save('/saveimage');
            },
            onDebug: function(type, string) {
            alert('error');
            alert(type + ": " + string);}, 
        });
```

backend:

`filecontent = self.request.body
    f = open('static/studentphotos/'+ filename +'.jpg','w')
    f.write(filecontent)
    f.close()"`

Answer (score 0):

Using your data as `x`, notice the `JFIF` in the output from [unhexlify](http://docs.python.org/library/binascii.html#binascii.unhexlify):

```
In [88]: binascii.unhexlify(x[:-1])
Out[88]: '\xff\xd8\xff\xe0\x00\x10JFIF...'
```

So it appears the data is a JPEG that needs to be unhexlified. Therefore try:

```
import binascii
filecontent = self.request.body 
with open('static/studentphotos/'+ filename +'.jpg','w')  as f:
    f.write(binascii.unhexlify(filecontent))
```

Comment: Thanks unutbu :)

In the end, I opted to use http://code.google.com/p/jpegcam/ instead. Much better documentation, clearer examples and form post saves as an image :)

I'll keep unhexlify in mind though. Thanks again